# How to make Spinner prioritize margins over width?

Tags: android, xml, constraints, spinner

In my toolbar I have two spinners next to each other and the 3 dots menu on the far right. This is the xml for them:

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/instrument_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/tuning_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/instrument_spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I set a constraint in the second spinner that is supposed to keep the menu icon clickable - however when the string is too long, the constraint is ignored, so it seems `layout_width="wrap_content"` is prioritized over the constraints. Is there a way to change this, so that when the constraint cannot be met due to the string length it simply doesn't show the full string? Something like `Longlonglong...` instead of `Longlonglongteststring` ?

Comment: Try using `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`. It basically does that, wrap content but prioritize constraints.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for, thanks!